# Ubuntu 15.10 + ZTE MF190 broadband modem (stick)

Tags: 15.10

Worked in Ubuntu 15.04. After upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 it is detected, i can create a connection entry with network manager wizzard but it doesn't connect anymore. Settings are the same as in Ubuntu 15.04 or older. Worked in all version until now without a problem. What changed in 15.10 and what should i do? :P

Comment: PS: it works under Windows 10 and on all previous versions of Ubuntu - tested!

Comment: I have exactly the same behaviour here. it worked in 15.04. and after the update i tries to connect but fails with 'IP-configuration was unavailable'